# What is iOS's equivalent of Java/Swing's FlowLayout?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, uiview, flowlayout

I'm trying to build a `UIView` that lays out other views using their intrinsic width, left to right, and then wraps if necessary.  `UICollectionView` seems overly complicated for what I need.  I also tried using the FlexLayout wrapper for Yoga, and couldn't seem to get the right incantation.  It seems like it should be much easier than this -- what's the simple solution?

Comment: Are there any other requirements besides what's in your first sentence? The more detail you provide, the more likely it is that someone who just knows iOS will be able to answer this (i.e., without having to be knowledgable about FlowLayout too).

Comment: No additional requirements.  Using intrinsic widths and wrapping are the core requirements.  I need to add/remove subviews, so it should wrap/unwrap as many times as necessary as views are added/removed.

Comment: Dynamically add/remove them, you mean, while the view is onscreen?

Comment: Yes.  I'll see if I can upload a screenshot of what I want to build, but the idea is pretty simple.  User checks between 1-12 checkbox at the bottom of the screen which add corresponding images to the top of the screen.  He may of course change his mind about what he wants to see, so he may check and uncheck many times.  The upper screen is naturally kept up to date.  Finally presses a button and the images are randomly reordered.

Comment: This first 25 seconds of this video give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, although it doesn't show the meeple-shapped images wrapping when more are selected than fit on the line. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mY19eAj5K0c&t=27s

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own UIView to solve the problem.  I doubt if it's very robust, but it solves my immediate needs.  Please, comment if you have an improvements to suggest.

```
import UIKit

class FlowLayout: UIView {
private var hgapValue: CGFloat = 0.0
private var vgapValue: CGFloat = 0.0

var hgap: CGFloat {
    set(newValue) {
        hgapValue = (newValue < 0) ? -newValue : newValue
    }
    get {
        return hgapValue
    }
}

var vgap: CGFloat {
    set(newValue) {
        vgapValue = (newValue < 0) ? -newValue : newValue
    }
    get {
        return vgapValue
    }
}

//initWithFrame to init view from code
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupView()
}

//initWithCode to init view from xib or storyboard
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupView()
}

override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
    refreshLayout()
}

//common func to init our view
private func setupView() {
    // backgroundColor = .red
}

public func refreshLayout() {
    var x: CGFloat = 0.0
    var y: CGFloat = 0.0

    for subview in subviews {
        subview.frame.origin.x = x
        subview.frame.origin.y = y
        x += subview.frame.width + hgapValue
        if x + subview.frame.width >= (subview.superview?.frame.width)! {
            x = 0.0
            y += subview.frame.height + vgapValue
        }

    }
    setNeedsDisplay()
}

}
```

Answer (score -2):

In interface builder, using UIStackView to achieve a simple alternative.

You can also turn on auto layout to make it naturally.

Comment: Keep in mind that `UIStackView` let's you setup one column or row of controls. It's nothing like Swing's FlowLayout or a collection view's flow layout.

Comment: UIStackView doesn't wrap, unfortunately.

Comment: About nested stackviews